# Compare two lists, create new column and assign 1 to matching data (RNA-seq genes)

Tags: r, compare

I have two dataframe:

- df1: big data frame, a gene list with ca. 20000 genes
- df2: small gene list (e.g. 50 genes).

Now I would like to find which genes from df2 are present in df1, add a new column in df1  and mark/highlight the matching genes with 1 and the nonmatching with 0.

I usually find out which genes are present in a list by using the subset function. I also know how to create a new table with only the matching genes etc. but I really do not know how to "mark them" in the same file, thus I thought of adding a column with 1 or 0. But it can be also true or false.

I hope I explain myself let me know if that is not the case

Thanks, Lore

Comment: Be careful with using `%in%`, if you have `NA` it gives unexpected results. Try `NA %in% 1`, it should give `NA` but gives `FALSE`.

Comment: @jay.sf Why should it return `NA` in that case? According to `?'%in%'`, returning `FALSE` is the intended behavior and it also explained why this is useful.

Comment: Posting my comment as an answer (couldn't find the exact duplicate post).

Answer (score 0):

Using `%in%`, then convert to integer:

```
df1$match <- as.integer(df1$gene %in% df2$gene)
```

---

Note the caveats mentioned by [jay.sf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6574038/jay-sf):

> Be careful with using %in%, if you have NA it gives unexpected results. Try NA %in% 1, it should give NA but gives FALSE.
> `%in%` is a great feature as it is. However, it is often recommended as a multivariate substitute for `==`. And there's the rub; where `==` yields NA, `%in%` won't, and through unawareness the naïve user might generate observations out of nothing.